# Saving read only database table in local variable during program execution

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

My application needs to read data from read only database and display it(I am using linq to fetch data)

Is it better to store database tables in local list during the execution and then using linq on local list instead of linq on entity?

Thanks

Comment: in almost all cases, linq on the IQueryable will be better. The query will take almost the same time, you'll not have that much data in your memory as it will be pre-filtered, and you'll less likely run into performance issues due to lazy loading/tracking.

Comment: It really depends on your setup - amount of data, how often you access it, latency to the server, amount of memory that data takes to store locally, and so on. Mostly, caching it is a good idea, you can either cache it locally or choose some remote caching implementation like Redis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it pointed in the comments, it depends on your case.

It is worth to keep in memory small amount of data that are accessed very often(kind of configuration info), 
in the other side it can be an overkill to keep in memory a considerable amount of data, in that case a db-read would be more preferable, so in the end you can decide by considering the size of data and number of reads over that data.